# Oxidation of Methanol - how to write the half reaction

Tags: alcohols

I am trying to write the half reaction equations for:

$$\ce{CH3OH + O2 -> HCOOH + H2O}$$

The primary goal for me here is to find out which reactant is oxidising without using prior knowledge of alcohol reactions.

So I wrote

$$\ce{CH3OH -> HCOOH}$$

and balanced the non hydrogens and non oxygens.
I then added $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O}$ to the sides appropriately
I calculated the charge of the alcohol by adding up the individual ionic charges of each atom in the molecule
Each side ended up with the equal charge of -2.
However I had no need to add any electrons into the equation to balance it out.

So how can I figure out whether it is oxidising if it doesn't indicate electron transfer? Is it some fundamental mistake in my method? Also, do alcohols have 0 net charge when dissolved in water?

Comment: If you don't respect oxygen's O's, chemists will be upset. See if this helps for starting: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Fundamentals/Chemical_Reactivity/Balancing_Organic_Redox_Reactions

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Keep CH SE Q titles in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not as easy as it looks, because there are two sorts of oxygen atoms. Some change their oxidation numbers, and some not. The first half-reaction is an oxidation of the reducing agent $\ce{CH3OH}$ which produces $\ce{HCOOH}$ on the right-hand side. The second half-reaction is a reduction of the oxidizing agent $\ce{O2}$ which produces $\ce{H2O}$ on the right-hand side. The two half-equations are : $$\ce{CH3OH + H2O -> HCOOH + 4 H+ + 4 e-}$$ $$\ce{O2 + 4 H+ + 4 e- -> 2 H2O}$$If you make the sum of these two half-equations, the $4$ e- and the $4$ $\ce{H+}$ disappear, and the final equation is : $$\ce{CH3OH + O2 -> HCOOH + H2O}$$